# Using Strophe + bosh always return AUTHFAIL status

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe

I am using strophe.js and bosh to connect to my openfire server.
Here are my openfire server details:

XMPP Domain Name:   subpm.localdomain
Bosh (http-bind) : http://subpm.localdomain:7070/http-bind/
ip: let say 120.12.2.1

I have used Adium and successfully connect via bosh. I have to mentioned the ip address instead of xmpp domain name. http://120.12.2.1:7070/http-bind/ and in jid i have also used the ip address.

But using strophe i am always getting AUTHFAIL status. I am using ip address just like Adium to connect.

Here is the code for the connection

```
var conn = new Strophe.Connection("http://120.12.2.1:7070/http-bind/");
conn.connect('bilkhan@120.12.2.1', 'password', function (status) {
  if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
      console.log("connected");
  } else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
      console.log("disconnected");
  }
});
```

Can anybody guide me in right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Can we see the (sanitized) code you have written to connect to the server?

Comment: @sme I have updated the question with the code for connection.

Comment: Do you have a domain name? Perhaps `bilkhan@120.12.2.1` is an invalid JID

Comment: @sme i am able to login using this jid through Adium messenger. I have specified  http://120.12.2.1:7070/http-bind/  as my bosh service url and port to be 7070. Server name  = 120.12.2.1. It worked and i got logged in.